# Why is $0$ an eigen value of $L_G$?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I am learning **Spectral Graph Theory**.

If the *Laplacian Matrix* of a graph $G=(V,E)$  is defined by

$(a_{ij})=-1 ;(i,j)\in E, d_i ; i=j$ and $0$ otherwise

then how does  it follow that $0$ is an eigen value of $L_G$  the *Laplacian Matrix* of $G$?

Comment: I believe it is explained under "Properties" e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make a quick write-up explaining the fact by following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix

- Each row and each column in the Laplacian matrix individually sum to zero, as in the i'th row there are entries $0$, $d_i$ and $-1$, the latter of which occurs $d_i$ times. Similar for columns.
- Because of this, when multiplying the Laplacian matrix by a vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ consisting only of ones, each entry in the resulting vector will be the sum of the corresponding row in the Laplacian, i.e. zero.
- Then $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector to the matrix, corresponding to the eigenvalue zero.

Comment: As a small addendum, the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is apparently equal to the number of connected components in the graph.